# Callback method with arguments of Qt dll (release) crashes in C# application

Tags: c#, qt, dll, callback

Release compiled Qt dll is dynamicaly loaded into C# application (dll managed wrapper) via DllImport.

Callback functions with arguments are invoked from the dll and run to the end, but then the application crashes with error in Qt5Core.dll.

The error is only on release assembly of the dll, debug is working good.
All methods work well.
Callbacks with no arguments are well too.
C# wrapper class is static.

Part of .h file of C++ Qt code:

```
typedef void(OnCallback) (int _arg);
extern"C"
{
  QT_DECL_EXPORT void setOnCallback(OnCallback _callback)
}
```

Part of C# code:

```
public static class CWrapper
{
  // Callback
  private delegate void TOnCallback(int _arg);
  private static void OnCallback(int _arg)
  {
    // we can even not use the argument
  } // last point before crash

  // Set callback to dll
  [DllImport(dllPath, CallingConvention.StdCall)]
  private static extern void setOnCallback(TOnCallback _OnCallback)
  private void Initialize()
  {
    setOnCallback(OnCallback);
  }
}
```

Sorry for english and thanks!

**update:**

I did this:

```
public static class CWrapper
{
  // Callback
  private delegate void TOnCallback(int _arg);
  private static TOnCallback OnCallbackStatic;    // <<< added
  private static void OnCallback(int _arg)
  {
    // we can even not use the argument
  } // last point before crash

  // Constructor                                  // <<< added
  static CWrapper()
  {
    OnCallbackStatic = OnCallback;
  }

  // Set callback to dll
  [DllImport(dllPath, CallingConvention.StdCall)]
  private static extern void setOnCallback(TOnCallback _OnCallback)
  private void Initialize()
  {
    setOnCallback(OnCallbackStatic);               // <<< changed
  }
}
```

Same result.

Comment: Your code is creating a delegate object.  But it is not referenced anywhere, the garbage collector is going to destroy it sooner or later.  After which your Qt code will bomb when it makes the callback.  That happens when you debug as well, you just didn't debug long enough.  You must use GCHandle.Alloc() or, easier, store it in a static variable so the GC can see it.

Comment: You mean
  `
    private delegate void TOnCallback(int _arg);
    private static TOnCallback OnCallbackStatic;
    private static void OnCallback(int _arg)
    {
      // we can even not use the argument
    }
    `
  and then call
    `
    private void Initialize()
    {
      OnCallbackStatic = OnCallback;
      setOnCallback(OnCallbackStatic);
    }
    `
? I did it - the same result.

Comment: Yes.  The "// we can even not use the argument" comment is hard to interpret but probably the second bug, you are missing the [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)] attribute on the delegate declaration.  Pretty hard to see how *that* could ever have worked in the debug build.  Did you actually test this?

Comment: Yes, Hans, i tested it. I updated the question. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I don't see you using the attribute.  The proper declaration on the C++ side so you don't need the attribute is `typedef void(__stdcall * OnCallback) (int _arg);`  After which you ought to get a non-random value for *_arg* and the stack no longer gets imbalanced.